# Is Monitoring Apps drastically impact battery life?

Tags: applications, battery, monitoring

A user on this [Product Hunt](https://www.producthunt.com/posts/menubar-stats) said that kinds of monitoring app such as iStatmenu, Menubar apps, that constantly poll the CPU for data, can drastically impact battery life. Is it true?

Comment: I use istat menus and I have not noticed significantly less battery life while using it. That's just my personal experience.

Answer (score 1):

Battery is affected with power consuming operations; cpu, hdd, bluetooth, wireless, etc.

So, yes. Amount of the cpu usage may drastically impact battery. Battery life is proportional to the frequency of charges/discharges.

Please consult to [apple page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203184)